# Problemas com caracter especial (ç à....)

Tags: python, reconhecimento-de-voz

estou fazendo um sistema com o Speech Recognition onde conforme eu vou falando ele vai salvando em um arquivo .db (ou .txt) porém percebi que aparece o seguinte caracteres quando falo alguma palavra com caracteres especiais como ç:�

Alguém saberia o motivo disso e como resolver isso? Já tentei achar em vários lugares porém não achei nada em relação a isso

Segue como ele print no terminal e como salva no doc:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a parte do código:

```
with SR.Microphone() as source:
        winsound.Beep(1500, 250) # Recording
        audio = r.listen(source)
        winsound.Beep(500, 250)   # End
        with open(nm_song, 'wb') as song:
              song.write(audio.get_wav_data())
  try:
        fala = r.recognize_google(audio, language="pt-BR")
        print('Você disse: ' + r.recognize_google(audio, language="pt-BR"))
        with open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Bots\\Klo\\yk12mmkiy78.txt', 'a') as f:
              f.write(fala + ';')
  except SR.UnknownValueError:
        _naoEntendi("Eu não entendi, poderia ser mais claro por favor?")
```

Comment: coloque a parte do código na qual ele salva no arquivo.

Comment: @WictorChaves editei com o código

Comment: Acredito que seu arquivo está com uma outra formatação de caracteres. Tente usar o ```encoding="utf-8"``` para forçar aceitar os caracteres especiais na frente do ```'a'``` para ver se o problema persiste.

Comment: @MuriloChaves muito obrigado, resolveu o problema!

Comment: @ErickVieira disponha, formalizei a resposta abaixo, caso queira valida-la como útil. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está ocasionando incompatibilidade de caracteres entre o que está digitando e o arquivo que deseja criar.

Tente usar o `encoding="utf-8"` na hora de adição das informações no txt.

```
with SR.Microphone() as source:
        winsound.Beep(1500, 250) # Recording
        audio = r.listen(source)
        winsound.Beep(500, 250)   # End
        with open(nm_song, 'wb') as song:
              song.write(audio.get_wav_data())
  try:
        fala = r.recognize_google(audio, language="pt-BR")
        print('Você disse: ' + r.recognize_google(audio, language="pt-BR"))
        with open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Bots\\Klo\\yk12mmkiy78.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
              f.write(fala + ';')
  except SR.UnknownValueError:
        _naoEntendi("Eu não entendi, poderia ser mais claro por favor?")
```

Comment: Desculpa a demora para responder, deu certo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Tranquilo @ErickVieira, que bom que deu tudo certo.